# Freshly formatted LUKS+ext4 external HDD keeps blinking

Tags: ext4, luks, external-hdd

After having formatted a USB-connected external HDD with LUKS+ext4 a short while ago, the LED on it keeps blinking when the drive is mounted, and only stops blinking when it's unmounted (LUKS still open).

I've found some webpages describing a similar phenomenon caused by a process called "ext4lazyinit", however, I can't find any process with that name or a similar name.

`iotop` also doesn't give me any clue.

`lsof` on the mountpoint says this:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

What's causing this constant LED blinking?

Comment: Try installing and running `sudo fatrace /mount/point`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Doesn't show anything.

Comment: What about blktrace?  That runs in the kernel on the block device, rather than in userspace, so should be able to see any IO activity on the block device. Try this on both the raw block device as well as the LUKS device, to see where the IO is being generated.

Comment: In case this would be the "lazyinit" (it should have stopped sooner or later, once it lazily finished initialization...), creating the ext4 filesystem with extended options `-E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0` will prevent lazyinit to happen (and take more time to execute the command).

Comment: @A.B Well, the drive wasn't busy in a way that would have prevented unmounting, but I didn't have the time to investigate any further, so I ran the "lazy" command and it seems to have fixed it.